# excel vba - userform that automatically fills the entire sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make it so userform automatically fills the entire sheet regardless of the current window size? When the user clicks the worksheet, the userform is automatically opened to fit the size of the worksheet.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can size the 'UserFrom' to overlap the current 'Excel Application' by putting this code into the UserForm as an event (click on your UserFrom and then copy and paste in the code below)

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Application
        Me.Left = .Left
        Me.Top = .Top
        Me.Height = .Height
        Me.Width = .Width
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you this is very good. However, I need the form to cover just the worksheet. The user needs to be able to see the tabs.